# Drools 6.5 Final CEP (Fusion) stability and performance problems

Tags: performance, drools, complex-event-processing

I am trying to see the max EPS capacity of Drools CEP. I am using 8 core 2.6 GHz CPU with 16 GB RAM. I am testing just 200 EPS with 2 rules.  Drools starts good but later (within 5 to 15 minutes) it stucks or starts NOT TO FIRE 
I have tested with fireAllRules and fireUntilHalt.

My Test Code:

```
package com.anet.correlation;
public class TestRealCase {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main.initTest();
    RulesRegistery.starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (RuleRunTimeRegistery.isFireuntilHalt) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new FT());
        t.start();

    }

    int i = 0;
    if (Main.ruleEngine != null) {
        while (true) {
            GeneralCorrelationObject ao1 = new GeneralCorrelationObject();

            ao1.setLOGTYPE("Firewalls");
            ao1.setSourceMachine("1.2.3.4" + (i % 500));
            ao1.setDestinationPort(i);
            Main.ruleEngine.evaluate(ao1);
            i++;

            if (i % RulesRegistery.EPS == 0)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    }
}
```

}

My DRL File

```
import com.anet.correlation.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.anet.ntLog.collector.*; 
import com.anet.alarm.*;
import com.anet.util.*;
import com.anet.correlation.operators.*; 
import com.anet.correlation.utils.*; 

declare GeneralCorrelationObject
               @role(event)
               @expires( 1200s )
end


rule "Port Scan_Port Scan_16"
salience 0
no-loop
when
$map1: Map()
from accumulate(
               generalcorrelationobject1:GeneralCorrelationObject(LOGTYPE=='Firewalls') over window:time( 1m )
 ,init( Map m = new HashMap();Hashtable ht= new Hashtable(); ),
action(
if(generalcorrelationobject1.getSourceMachine()==null)
{
               return;
}
               String key="SourceMachine="+generalcorrelationobject1.getSourceMachine();
               List list = (List)m.get(key);
               if( list == null )
                              list = new ArrayList();
Object val1=generalcorrelationobject1.getDestinationPort();
String value1;
if (val1 instanceof Integer)
               value1=val1+"";
else
               value1=(String)val1;

String not_key=value1;
if (ht.containsKey(key)){
               Hashtable ht_hash=(Hashtable)ht.get(key);
               Object ht_val=ht_hash.get(not_key);
               String ht_value;
               if (ht_val instanceof Integer)
                              ht_value=ht_val+"";
               else
                              ht_value=(String)ht_val;
               if (!not_key.equalsIgnoreCase(ht_value)){
                              ht_hash.put(not_key, not_key); 
               ht.put(key, ht_hash); 
                              list.add( generalcorrelationobject1 );
               }
}
else{
Hashtable ht_hash=new Hashtable(); 
               ht_hash.put(not_key, not_key);
               ht.put(key, ht_hash);
               list.add( generalcorrelationobject1 );
}
               m.put(key,list);),
               result( m ) 
)
then
/*
if ((new CheckListSize()).check($map1,10)){
System.out.println("Done");


}
*/



            Iterator s = $map1.keySet().iterator();
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) s.next();
                List list = (List) $map1.get(key);

                System.out.println(key+" : "+list.size());

            }




end




rule "Port eee Scan_161"
salience 100
no-loop
when

              ee:GeneralCorrelationObject() 
then

if (RulesRegistery.numberofsingleruleexecution % RulesRegistery.printEPS == 0) {
System.out.println(ee.getSourceMachine());
}

RulesRegistery.numberofsingleruleexecution++;
end
```

RuleEngine Code

```
package com.anet.correlation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.kie.api.KieBase;
import org.kie.api.KieBaseConfiguration;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieBuilder;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieFileSystem;
import org.kie.api.builder.Message;
import org.kie.api.builder.ReleaseId;
import org.kie.api.conf.EventProcessingOption;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSessionConfiguration;
import org.kie.internal.builder.conf.RuleEngineOption;

import org.kie.internal.KnowledgeBase;
import org.kie.internal.KnowledgeBaseFactory;
import org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
import org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.kie.api.io.ResourceType;

public final class RulesEngine {
    KieSession ksession;
    KieBuilder kbuilder;

    public static String header = null;


    public RulesEngine(boolean b) {
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

        KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
        kfs.write("src/main/resources/bench.drl", getRule());

        this.kbuilder = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);

        this.kbuilder.buildAll();
        if (this.kbuilder.getResults().hasMessages(new Message.Level[] { Message.Level.ERROR })) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(this.kbuilder.getResults().toString());
        }
        ReleaseId relId = this.kbuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId();

        KieContainer kcontainer = ks.newKieContainer(relId);
        KieBaseConfiguration kbconf = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();

        kbconf.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
        kbconf.setOption(RuleEngineOption.PHREAK);
        // kbconf.setOption(RuleEngineOption.RETEOO);
        System.out.println("KB " + kbconf.getProperty("drools.ruleEngine"));
        KieBase kbase = kcontainer.newKieBase(kbconf);
        KieSessionConfiguration ksconf = ks.newKieSessionConfiguration();

        this.ksession = kbase.newKieSession(ksconf, null);

    }

    String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {

                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            String rule = (sb.toString());

            System.out.println("New Final");
            System.out.println(rule);
            return rule;
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    public String getRule() {
        try {
            return readFile(".." + File.separator + "rules" + File.separator + "all.drl");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void evaluate(GeneralCorrelationObject message) {

        if (message == null) {

            System.out.println("message null ");

            return;
        }
        if (ksession == null) {

            System.out.println("ksession null ");

            return;
        }

        try {
            Long n = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (RulesRegistery.numberofrules % RulesRegistery.printEPS == 0) {

                System.out.println("Inserting Objects " + RulesRegistery.numberofrules + " EPS : "
                        + (RulesRegistery.numberofrules / ((n - RulesRegistery.starttime) / 1000)) + " : Total time "
                        + ((n - RulesRegistery.starttime) / (1000 * 60)) + " : " + new Date());
            }

            ksession.insert(message);

            if (RulesRegistery.numberofrules % RulesRegistery.printEPS == 0) {
                System.out.println("Inserted Objects " + RulesRegistery.numberofrules + " EPS : "
                        + (RulesRegistery.numberofrules / ((n - RulesRegistery.starttime) / 1000)) + " : Total time "
                        + ((n - RulesRegistery.starttime) / (1000 * 60)) + " : " + new Date());
            }

            if (!RuleRunTimeRegistery.isFireuntilHalt) {


                    if (RulesRegistery.numberofrules % RulesRegistery.printEPS == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Running Rules " + RulesRegistery.numberofrules + " EPS : "
                                + (RulesRegistery.numberofrules / ((n - RulesRegistery.starttime) / 1000))
                                + " : Total time " + ((n - RulesRegistery.starttime) / (1000 * 60)) + " : "
                                + new Date());
                    }
                    ksession.fireAllRules();

                    if (RulesRegistery.numberofrules % RulesRegistery.printEPS == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Runned Rules " + RulesRegistery.numberofrules + " EPS : "
                                + (RulesRegistery.numberofrules / ((n - RulesRegistery.starttime) / 1000))
                                + " : Total time " + ((n - RulesRegistery.starttime) / (1000 * 60)) + " : "
                                + new Date());
                    }


            }

            RulesRegistery.numberofrules++;
            RuleRunTimeRegistery.lasttiem = n;
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've missed it: there isn't a `retract` statement in your code. This means that you keep inserting objects, with the usual result, after some time.

Retract facts as soon they aren't needed any more in any of your rules.